# Javascript date and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, date

I'm very new to Javascript. I'm not exactly sure how to call it or use it. And some websites aren't that much of a help. So I thought you guys would be a great help.

I have this so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="2">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Current Time</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navBar">
        <a class="nav" href="http://www.blah.com">blah</a>
        <a class="nav" href="http://www.blah2.com">blah2</a>
        <a class="nav" href="https://www.blah3.com">blah3</a>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function getBostonDate(){
                var currentDate = new Date();
                var dateTime = "Boston current time: " + currentDate.getHours() + ":" + currentDate.getMiutes() + ":" + currentDate.getSeconds();
                document.write(dateTime);
            }
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I want it to just display a couple of links in the header, and then display the date. (I am in Boston according to my profile so I used that.)

I also tried to put it in it's own .js file and calling it externally and placing that line of code in the  part of the HTML. But even then, I have no idea how to call it in the place I want it to be called (after the links). Please help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It should be 'getMinutes()' instead of 'getMiutes()'

Comment: @Samurai Oh wow, didn't see my spelling error, thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a div to your code where you want to display the time, such as

```
<div id="display_time"></div>
```

and then, instead of `document.write...` use:

```
document.getElementById("display_time").innerHTML=dateTime;
```

If you want your time to be updated constantly, use `setInterval`, as in:

```
setInterval( 
    // YOUR FUNCTION HERE
,1000);
```

That will recalculate the time and redisplay it every 1000 ms (=1s).

EDIT:
As mentioned by Jon P, you have to call the function (and not only define it).
A way to do it is to call it once the page body has loaded. All you have to do is adding it to your `body` tag as in:

```
<body onload="setInterval(getBostonDate(),1000);">
```

Alternatively, you can just call it inside your script, as in

```
setInterval(getBostonDate(),1000);
```

Also, as mentioned by Samurai, don't forget to correct your typo: `getMinutes()` instead of `getMiutes()`

Comment: To make this answer more complete include how to have the run on page load as this is the crux of the OP's problem. He has set a function but never calls it.

Comment: @JonP Thanks for the comment. I updated it. Feel free to edit the answer if you think it can be improved :D

Comment: Thanks! This worked really well. For some reason, I looked up examples of JS in HTML, but I couldn't seem to find where they were calling the actual "function" so I always thought they just placed the script where they wanted it to work. Thanks so much for explaining it really well.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're new to javascript, I think it would be a good idea to start learning jQuery instead of going with native javascript. Here's the jQuery way of doing it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(ShowTime, 1000);
});

function ShowTime() {

    var TheDate = new Date();

    var TheHour = TheDate.getHours();
    var TheMinutes = TheDate.getMinutes();
    var TheSeconds = TheDate.getSeconds();

    TheSeconds = (TheSeconds < 10) ? "0" + TheSeconds :  TheSeconds;

    var TheTime = "Boston current time: " + TheHour + ":" +TheMinutes + ":" + TheSeconds;

    $('#TheDate').html(TheTime);     
}
```

And here's the **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gkJyA/1/)**

Comment: I'm going to respectfully disagree about learning jQuery over native javascript. I think a solid grounding in javscript should be obtained first. Don't get me wrong I love jQuery but I have seen it miss-used, or used poorly to0 many times by people who have a little understading of javascript. I equate it to saying don't worry about learning HTML, just use Dreamweaver.

Comment: @JonP +1 I quite agree. A basic grounding in JS is essential before dabbling with jQuery.

Comment: Who knows if it's better to start with native javascript or jQuery; it's a matter of opinion and some people will share your opinion and others will not. For me, I'm part of the people who think it's better to start with jQuery so that you can get things done and learn javascript while learning jQuery. With native javascript you have to deal with browser issues and such and I think it's much harder to learn that way. I'd compare javascript to C/C++ and jQuery to C#/Java. Yes, you can learn programming AND start with pointers or you can start with a managed language. Opinions are not reality.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this in case you want to load this javascript on link click:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="2">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Current Time</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navBar">
        <a class="nav" onclick="getBostonDate()" href="http://www.blah.com">blah</a>
        <a class="nav" onclick="getBostonDate()" href="http://www.blah2.com">blah2</a>
        <a class="nav" onclick="getBostonDate()" href="https://www.blah3.com">blah3</a>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function getBostonDate(){
                var currentDate = new Date();
                var dateTime = "Boston current time: " + currentDate.getHours() + ":" + currentDate.getMiutes() + ":" + currentDate.getSeconds();
                document.write(dateTime);
            }
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**In case you want it to load on form load Use this:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="2">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Current Time</title>
</head>
<body onload="getBostonDate()">
    <div class="navBar">
        <a class="nav" href="http://www.blah.com">blah</a>
        <a class="nav" href="http://www.blah2.com">blah2</a>
        <a class="nav" href="https://www.blah3.com">blah3</a>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function getBostonDate(){
                var currentDate = new Date();
                var dateTime = "Boston current time: " + currentDate.getHours() + ":" + currentDate.getMiutes() + ":" + currentDate.getSeconds();
                document.write(dateTime);
            }
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<body onload="getBostonDate()">
    <div class="navBar">
        <a class="nav" href="http://www.blah.com">blah</a>
        <a class="nav" href="http://www.blah2.com">blah2</a>
        <a class="nav" href="https://www.blah3.com">blah3</a>
    <span id="myBostonTimeSpan"></span>
    </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function getBostonDate(){
                var currentDate = new Date();
                var dateTime = "Boston current time: " + currentDate.getHours() + ":" + currentDate.getMinutes() + ":" + currentDate.getSeconds();
                document.getElementById("myBostonTimeSpan").innerHTML=dateTime;
            }

        </script>
</body>
```

Once you've learned some javascript, you might also want to have a look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

Comment: See my comment on Frenchies answer for my feeling on directing javascript noobs straight to jQuery.

Comment: @JonP, That's a fair comment. Building a foundation before the house always helps :) I've modified my answer somewhat...

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you have set the function but you don't call it anywhere. Your simplest solution would be to make the script naked, i.e Take it out of the function.

```
<div class="navBar">
        <a class="nav" href="http://www.blah.com">blah</a>
        <a class="nav" href="http://www.blah2.com">blah2</a>
        <a class="nav" href="https://www.blah3.com">blah3</a>
        <script type="text/javascript">

                var currentDate = new Date();
                var dateTime = "Boston current time: " + currentDate.getHours() + ":" + currentDate.getMiutes() + ":" + currentDate.getSeconds();
                document.write(dateTime);

        </script>
    </div>
```

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/LpMeR/

This will fix your problem but is not the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Can try this as well. It will auto reflect the system timezone. Add it where ever you want.

```
<div id="time"></div>
<script>
    function getCurrentTime() {
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = d;
    }
    setInterval('getCurrentTime()', 1000);
</script>
```